# How do I vertically flip my webcam's image?

Tags: webcam, effects

My USB webcam is precariously mounted on the desk I'm using. The clamp damages my monitor; Better lighting etc. etc.

Works like a charm but all that is needed is to **vertically flip** the picture for use in Skype, G+ Hangouts etc.

I am at a loss as to how this is accomplished in Ubuntu 11.10.

Closest I have come is [a thread](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/cheese-list/2011-December/msg00002.html) mentioning *omitted effects from cheese*.

I can't find anything else on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**WebcamStudio**](http://www.ws4gl.org/) allows you to run several effects at once, between other interesting features like running images, videos and other stuff as your webcam in order to be streamed in almost any via (web service, video conferencing system, chat, etc.)

In the next screenshot I am using my webcam in order to show the images flipped horizontally (up to down), but you can both invert horizontally, vertically and to run several effects at once.

[image]

Note: I am using Cheese in order to preview the webcam's output.

Aditionally you may wish to take a look at this answer by @Veazer: https://askubuntu.com/a/124934/9598 Posted here for your convenience:

> I think you'll need to create a launcher script for each application
>   that needs this fix. For example, if you wanted a script for Skype
>   that flips the video horizontally this should work:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> export LIBV4LCONTROL_FLAGS=1 && LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib32/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype
> ```
>
> If the image is not flipping correctly, try different values for
>   LIBV4LCONTROL_FLAGS. My camera requires a vertical flip so I use '2'.
>   I haven't used this on 11.10 until today when I saw your message, but
>   it seems to be working.

No working for me but @Luis Alvarado informs that it works, if this last one is working for you please don't forget to give credit to its author.

Good luck!

Comment: You sir, are a gentleman and a scholar... Thank you so much :D

Comment: WebcamStudio seems to be no longer maintained. Is there an alternative for this as of 2021?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install `video4linux control panel` via the software center. That should be able to do it.

Comment: Are you referring to v4l2ucp? I don't think it can flip video.

Comment: hm ... right, seems that option is no longer available ...

Comment: took me a while to realise that :)