# How can I horizontally invert the video output of the webcam

Tags: 11.10, webcam

When I use for example Cheese I want that when I move my right hand, in the video and see myself moving the right hand of my image instead of me moving the left hand. What I mean with this is that if my move my right side, in the video the right side should move, not the left side (as seen through the eye of the webcam). Basically to invert horizontally the image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you'll need to create a launcher script for each application that needs this fix. For example, if you wanted a script for Skype that flips the video horizontally this should work:

```
#!/bin/bash
export LIBV4LCONTROL_FLAGS=1 && LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib32/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype
```

If the image is not flipping correctly, try different values for `LIBV4LCONTROL_FLAGS`. My camera requires a vertical flip so I use '2'. I haven't used this on 11.10 until today when I saw your message, but it seems to be working.

Comment: Wow very nice. It works. Thanks for the info about Flags.